# What is the risk of collisions when relying on Python hash function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, hash

In my program I need to store data related to many (we talk hundreds of thousands, millions) game board states. For that I use a dict.

```
class BoardState(object):
    def __init__(self, ...):
        # ...
        self.board = [ [ None ] * self.cols for _ in xrange(self.rows) ]

    def __hash__(self):
        board_tuple = tuple([ tuple(row) for row in self.board ])
        return hash(board_tuple)

    # ...
```

`self.board` is a 2D list, in my main use case, with 6 rows and 7 columns.

At the beginning I indexed the `dict` with `BoardState` objects. But since I don't use `BoardState` objects stored in `dict` for other purpose than future lookup I noticed that I can save memory by indexing with `hash(board_state)` (this version uses 4 times less memory).

What is the chance that two different `BoardState` objects (with different `board`s inside) will result in the same value after `hash`ing?

To clarify a bit, that's how I store and retrieve values from `dict`:

```
board_state = BoardState(...)
my_values[hash(board_state)] = { ... }
...
other_val_with_board_state = source_function()
retrieved = my_values[hash(other_val_with_board_state)]
```

(As I mentioned earlier, I index with result from `hash()` to save memory, since I don't use `BoardState` objects later.)

---

**UPDATE** Now I'm wondering if maybe using string representation of `board_state.board` as index would be a good solution to my problem.

Comment: Now I see what u are tying to do...Hard to say, there might be collisions. If you want to be more secure you should use more advanced hashing inside hashlib. Or define your own hashing which ensure unique results with regards to the board configuration.

Comment: Relevant post http://stackoverflow.com/a/9010557/2243104

Comment: @Reti43 Yeah, it is somehow. But I don't want to waste memory space with objects I would use only for their __eq__ method.

Comment: You could also just use the tuple of tuples (board_tuple) as a dictionary key, instead of its hash. No need to make a new class if the only interesting part is board_tuple.

Comment: @Rob Board list / tuple is key to the state but there are also helper vars like rows and cols, and methods which operate on the state. Yes, I could also use that tuple as index but string would probably take less memory space.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Short answer: use `hashlib` instead.

---

You shouldn't rely on `hash` if your program cannot handle the collisions or you want to [save hash values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27522626/4687565) or use multiprocessing.

Python hash function converts maps data to 64 bits (range of int). The most basic analysis of hashing is limited to viewing it as birthday problem. There is a nice [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22029380/4687565) and a detailed [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack#Mathematics) about that. Typical quote is "if you have less than billions of elements you should not worry". This is very simplistic view however.

As an anecdote: I've recently ran `hash` over `8.7e6` unique short strings created manually by humans. The [mathematical expectation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35791/birthday-problem-expected-number-of-collisions) of the number of collisions for 64 bit hash is `4e-6`. I got 32. Fun fact: `hash(chr(9786)) == hash(chr(58)+chr(38))` ('☺' collides with ':&') (as of Python3.8.10).

Cryptographic functions from `hashlib` are way [more resistant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4014090/4687565) to collisions. Something like `hashlib.sha256(pickle.dumps(my_obj,1))` might even be faster than conversion to tuples.

---

If the memory concern is the reason for hashing, one should first consider representing the data with lesser amount of bytes in the first place. Specifying `__slots__` and reducing the number of the nested objects are first things that come to mind. However for the case of small objects this will be an uphill battle due to amount of scaffolding each python object needs.

If we take chess for example the full state [can be stored](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/34508) in 24 bytes or more comfortably, in 32 bytes (64 cells each needing 4 bits to represent its contents). The best we can get with python is `bytes` which will take 65 bits (33 bytes of service info) and will require additional manipulations to push two 4-bit chunks into a single byte. The other alternative might be `bitarray.frozenbitarray` which will need 112 bytes to store the same amount of useful information (80 bytes of info). But hey, it still beats tuples within tuples, where there is [40 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30316760/4687565) of scaffolding per tuple.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not sure what chance there is in getting the same value after hashing, presumably it is possible and could be problematic.

That being said, if you don't use `BoardState` objects stored in the dict for any purpose other than lookup, would it be feasible for you to add an `id` property to the BoardState class that is generated uniquely on `__init__` (i.e. set to a global counter incremented by 1 after each new BoardState object is created)?  Then you could use `id` as the key to your dictionary for future lookup and avoid any potential collision issues.

Comment: I can't do that, because it's possible that the same BoardState will be created in future and would't have the same id.

Comment: If 2 BoardState objects with same configuration are the same, why are you worrying of collisions? I do not quite get your use case.

Comment: @xbirkettx Am I asking if two different, let's say 6x7 boards (2D lists/tuples), could have the same hash. BTW If you don't mention me in the comment I don't get the notification since it's not my answer.

Comment: @Luke you have redefined your hash, but are you still using a dict for lookup? If so you don't have to worry about collisions

Comment: @xbirkettx But I'm doing lookup by the hash. So the values for those two states with collision would be shared between them.

Answer (score -1):

To know the risk of collision, we would have to take a look at the hash function implementation.
The main idea is that there is a start from a space, let's say A (all the form that the variable board_tuple can take) to a other space B (result of hash function) through the hash function H.

The risk of collision come from two things :

- the size of spaces : if you have 2 `board_tuple` possibilities and B has a size of 10⁶. Then there is really few chances that a collision will occur. In an other hand, if you can have 1000 `board_tuple` and H is resulting in a space B of 16, then it is almost for sure that collision will happen.
- The hash function in itself. If the hash function is h(x) = 2, then there will always be collision.

However do not worry too much, hash function are well made and I am almost sure that they are handling collisions smartly with some classic strategies :

- Do a rerun of the hash function until there is no collision
- Store as an array of elements resulting in the same hash instead of having a collision
  ....

Comment: I'm afraid you don't answer the question. You just describe some facts about hashing and then conclude that we should look into Python's hash implementation to how whether and how frequently a collision can occur. Which is what the question is asking about. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9010557/2243104) and links therein go into more detail about the specifics.